# Date picker is not working in nested repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have tried datepicker by JQuery and Ajax calendarExtender also. But some how while clicking on textbox, extender is not showing calendar.

I have attached code below.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt_Order" OnItemDataBound ="rpt_Item_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li> 
            Planned Date
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt_FinalCart" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" tabindex="11" CssClass="datepickers" ID="txtPlannedDate" MaxLength="16" onkeypress="return validateQty(event);" onkeydown ="return validateQty1(event);"   Style="text-align:center; background-color:#EFEFEF; font-size:14px; font-weight:600;" Width="90%" Height="20px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID ="CalEx" runat ="server" TargetControlID ="txtPlannedDate"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>                             
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>                                
       </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Just curious: why `<HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>` and not `<HeaderTemplate />`?

Comment: any script errors in your console?

Comment: no any script errors